# Data transfer out in Azure storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Is there any reason why during a writing to azure storage table I have huge **data transfer out**? There is no more operations with the storage, only writing. 
[image]
There is one operation which happens many times:

```cs
await keyRepository.InsertEntityAsync(new KeyEntity
{
    PartitionKey = item.PartitionKey,
    RowKey = item.RowKey
});
```

`InsertEntityAsync` looks like:

```cs
public async Task InsertEntityAsync(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
    await _cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Insert(entity));
}
```

creation of `_cloudTable`:

```cs
private readonly CloudTable _cloudTable;

CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
TableRequestOptions tableRequestOptions = new TableRequestOptions { RetryPolicy = retryPolicy };
CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
cloudTableClient.DefaultRequestOptions = tableRequestOptions;
_cloudTable = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
_cloudTable.CreateIfNotExists();
```

**Edit 1**

Read - 45.5 GB

Write - 39.4 GB

Comment: How do you define "huge"? Your chart doesn't show units (nor do we know anything about your frequency of inserts, which is relevant since each REST call does have some type of response). And how do you know the outbound transfer is solely from writing to table storage?

Comment: based on the chart I spend 3.96$ for data transfer out during last 2 days. based on [price](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/pricing/details/bandwidth/) it is 45.5 GB

Comment: How much data you're writing to the table?

Comment: There is a problem with metrics in Azure right now, but based on price I write about 39.4 GB

Comment: Forgot to ask: where is your code running? Same region as your storage account, or a different region?

Comment: same region as storage account

Answer (score 0):

According to that article :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity

the entity is returned in the body of the response.

If you prefer to save output bandwith, you could add the following header to your request :

```
Prefer : return-no-content
```

**Edit 1**

```
Prefer : return-no-content
```

Is sent by default

But it is possible to control sending of headers through :

```
  OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContext { };
  operationContext.UserHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "Prefer", "return-no-content" }
  };
  table.Execute(insertOperation, null, operationContext: operationContext);
```

Nonetheless in my trials, I get a little bit more than 600 bytes sent in reponse (only headers, no body)

**Edit 2**

I also tried batch send, but if the number of requests is lowered, the global bandwidth used is not minimized

Comment: Thanks, it looks interesting, but I use Azure SDK, there is default value `return-no-content`, even when I set it explicitly, data transfer out is same.